How do I add a final cumulative row to a CSV using @json2csv/node transforms?
I'm playing around with this example from the @json2csv/node docs using a custom transform (see below), and I'm wondering if it'd be possible to add a final row where the price is summed up. Thus instead of this CSV:
"carModel","price"
"AUDI",0
"BMW",15
"MERCEDES",20
"PORSCHE",30
"TESLA",50

I'd get:
"carModel","price"
"AUDI",0
"BMW",15
"MERCEDES",20
"PORSCHE",30
"TESLA",50
,115

MWE: Note this is a MWE and in reality, I'm doing a bunch of other calculations inside the transformer. Thus simply adding a final row with the price summed up before calling the parser isn't feasible.
const { Parser } = require('@json2csv/plainjs');

const data = [
  { "carModel": "Audi", "price": 0 },
  { "carModel": "BMW", "price": 15000 },
  { "carModel": "Mercedes", "price": 20000 },
  { "carModel": "Porsche", "price": 30000 },
  { "carModel": "Tesla", "price": 50000, }
];

function transformRow() {
  return (item) => ({
    ...item,
    carModel: item.carModel.toUpperCase(),
    price: item.price / 1000,
  });
}

try {
  const opts = {
    transforms: [
    transformRow(),
    ]
  };
  const parser = new Parser(opts);
  const csv = parser.parse(data);
  console.log(csv);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}


You could add a variable inside the transformer, which would hold data you need, and also add counter, which would track the rows, and then upon last row, add the final row along with the cumulative price:
// pass the total rows
transformRow(data.length),

setup cumulative price and counter for reuse on each row/iteration:
function transformRow(total) {

 let cumulativePrice, i;
  cumulativePrice = i = 0;

  return (item) => {
  
    cumulativePrice += item.price / 1000;
    i++;
   //...

upon final row, add cumulative price after the last row
if (i === total) {
  return [{
    ...item,
    carModel: item.carModel.toUpperCase(),
    price: item.price / 1000,
  }, {
    price: cumulativePrice
  }];

code (modify/refactor as needed):
const { Parser } = require('@json2csv/plainjs');

const data = [
  { "carModel": "Audi", "price": 0 },
  { "carModel": "BMW", "price": 15000 },
  { "carModel": "Mercedes", "price": 20000 },
  { "carModel": "Porsche", "price": 30000 },
  { "carModel": "Tesla", "price": 50000, }
];


function transformRow(total) {

  let cumulativePrice, i;
  cumulativePrice = i = 0;

  return (item) => {
  
    cumulativePrice += item.price / 1000;
    i++;
    
    if (i === total) {
      return [{
        ...item,
        carModel: item.carModel.toUpperCase(),
        price: item.price / 1000,
      }, {
        price: cumulativePrice
      }];      
    } else {
      return {
        ...item,
        carModel: item.carModel.toUpperCase(),
        price: item.price / 1000,
      };
    }
  };
}

try {
  const opts = {
    transforms: [
      transformRow(data.length),
    ]
  };
  const parser = new Parser(opts);
  const csv = parser.parse(data);
  console.log(csv);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}

result:
"carModel","price"
"AUDI",0
"BMW",15
"MERCEDES",20
"PORSCHE",30
"TESLA",50
,115


I ended up doing this and was planning to post an answer but you won the race :) Thanks!
